# For multiple photodiodes looking at a different angle could I connect them to a 4071 ic or something similar?

Tags: pcb, photodiode

I want to make many photodiodes at different angles and I want to be able to tell where IR light is coming from. I am designing a PCB using a Teensy 4.1 and would like to be able to identify from what angle an object is coming from, but I do not have enough pins for all of the photodiodes. To be able to identify from which photodiode the light is coming from, would I use a decade counter such as a 4017 for this?

Comment: A photodiode is an analog device, while a 4017 expects digital signals following particular voltage levels. Chances are, it won't work as expected unless you first convert each individual photodiode signal to a digital signal, but there may be other analog approaches for multiplexing the signals together. Can you draw a schematic showing how you are currently hooking up one photodiode, and mark how you intend to use the 4017?

Comment: Use an analogue multiplexor.

Comment: what response time are you aiming for? ... maybe a mechanical solution could work ... one sensor and a rotating mirror

Comment: Which photo diodes are you be using?

Comment: Rather than *photo-diode* detectors, I can imagine a circuit marrying a CD4017 with ten *photo-transistors* of the two-terminal kind...one analog output A serial-in parallel-out shift register chip is another option instead of CD4017.